# How can I optimize DAL web2py query?

Tags: python, mysql, web2py, database-abstraction

```
result = db((db.company.location.belongs(locations)) &
            (db.company.emp_id.belongs(employee_ids)) &
            (db.company.type.belongs(types))).select()
```

`locations` is list of location ids

`employee_ids` is list of employee ids

`types = ['General', 'office', 'e-commerce']`

This query return 60,000 records and takes 1 minute to complete. How can I optimize it or split it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found myself a solution.

Company table has 20 columns. 
It is not specified in query that which fields to select, query returns 60,000 records each having 20 fields.

I optimized query by selecting only those column which are needed.

I needed only id and name. So I changed the query to following, now query takes only 10 seconds (previous was 60 seconds):

```
result = db((db.company.location.belongs(locations)) &
            (db.company.emp_id.belongs(employee_ids)) &
            (db.company.type.belongs(types))).select(db.company.id, db.company.name)
```

Comment: That sure makes a huge difference. By your previous code, i assumed that you wanted `db.company.ALL` as a return form your select. Since dealing with DB IO usually is the most time consuming operation, it's always a good practice to fetch only the necessary data.
Also, if you're don't care about a updated result, you might also consider caching that select result.
"""
db((db.company.location.belongs(locations)) &
            (db.company.emp_id.belongs(employee_ids)) &
            (db.company.type.belongs(types))).select(db.company.id, db.company.name, cache=(cache.ram,3600),cacheable=True)
"""

Comment: Wasn't sure if i should post that as a comment or another answer :P

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your DAL query takes ~1 minute is because the return of the `.select()` method is a `Rows` instance, which contains 60,000 `Row` objects. Many instantiations of those classes consists in a time and memory consuming operation. 
As a solution, you could:

- Split that query in pieces of **X**, using the [limit by](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#orderby--groupby--limitby--distinct--having-orderby_on_limitby-left-cache) parameter: `.select(limitby=(0, X))` or;
- Use [executesql](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#executesql) `db().executesql(SELECT * FROM...)` to construct your query using SQL. The return would be tuples, theres isn't any Row or Rows instantiations and its much faster, but you would have the downside of not being able to enjoy the benefits of a `Row` object;

If any of the above solved your problem, and you have a really time consuming operation, you could try to use the split solution along with threads.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Able to reduce time with this, Also I found myself a solution. Posted a new answer.